# How would I get just the numbers out of the below array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to get an alert for only the numbers from this array but cant! Thanks in advance

```
var clenk = [0, null, 42, undefined, "", true, false, NaN, "", "foo bar"];
var filteredArr = clenk.filter(function(val) {
return !(val === isNaN);
});
alert(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
var clenk = [0, null, 42, undefined, "", true, false, NaN, "", "foo bar"];
var filteredArr = clenk.filter(function(val) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(val));
});
alert(filteredArr);
```

- [Why is isNaN() not working](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Confusing_special-case_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator to detect the type of `val`.

```
var clenk = [0, null, 42, undefined, "", true, false, NaN, "", "foo bar"];
var filteredArr = clenk.filter(function(val) {
    return (typeof val === "number" && !isNaN(val));
});
alert(filteredArr);
```

Comment: cheers that works a treat. just wondering why i need "number" in there?

Comment: because isNaN converts the variable to number then checks if it's NaN.so `isNaN('32');` will return false althoug you passed a string not number